# In electron are fs operations done in ipcRenderer or ipcMain

Tags: node.js, electron

At the moment I read files within the `front/script/index.js` (ipcRenderer)

```
 readTitles('./data').map(({title, dir}) => {
    el = document.createElement("li");
    text = document.createTextNode(`${title.split('.md')[0]}`);
    el.appendChild(text)
    readFileContent(dir, el)
    document.getElementById('titles').appendChild(el)
})
```

Then when I need a file to be create I am asking ipcMain to do it

```
   form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        ipcRenderer.send(NEW_DOCUMENT_SAVE_NEEDED, { // alerting ./main.js
            fileName: e.target[0].value
          })
        console.log(e.target[0].value)
    })
```

And basically going back and forth

```
ipcMain.on(NEW_DOCUMENT_SAVE_NEEDED, (event, {fileName}) => {
        fs.writeFile(`./${fileName}.md`, "Hey there!", function(err) {
            if(err) { return console.log(err); }
            console.log("The file was saved!");

        });
        window.webContents.send(FILE_CREATED, {
            message: 'The file was saved!', 
            payload: {
                fileName,
                dir: `./data/${fileName}.md`
            }
        })
    })
```

Instead of sending `NEW_DOCUMENT_SAVE_NEEDED` I could just do the `fs.writeFile` in there, just as I did `fs.readdirSync` to read all the files.

I know there are things I can't do in ipcRenderer but I can do `fs` operations, is there a need to go back and forth on these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.
If you only have small amounts of data to write into files, you can do it in the renderer.js.
If you have large amounts of data and don't want your UI to get blocked, you should move your fs operations to a different process.

Electron is tricky here, even doing it in the main.js will still block the UI: [Horror of Electron Main Process](https://medium.com/actualbudget/the-horror-of-blocking-electrons-main-process-351bf11a763c)
Best practice here is to create a second BrowserWindow, make it invisible and do the heavy operations there, in your case fs.writeFile(). This will be a different process and won't block the UI.

Comment: As this is literally my first demo app slightly bigger then a hello world, I gather I should put the fs operations in the main.js, not that it would make a big difference but slightly better practice (?)
Anyway, thanks

Comment: You will probably not notice a difference in performance with a single file write operation, so no worries.